# Можно ли узнать какие слова иерархически связаны с другим словом(являются его потомками) в предложении с помощью синтаксического анализа Natasha?

Tags: python, синтаксический-анализ, nltk, естественный-язык, natasha

Можно ли узнать какие слова иерархически связаны с другим словом(являются его потомками) в предложении с помощью синтаксического анализа Natasha? Нужно чтобы они были в подчиненной роли по отношению к этому другому слову.

Comment: Эээ, непонятно. Приведите какие-нибудь примеры, что ли. Что за слова-потомки такие?

Comment: Например предложение:"На столе лежит красное яблоко". Я хочу узнать какие слова относятся к слову "лежит". Т.е. в данном случае ответ будет "На столе".

Comment: А к "яблоку" слово "лежит" разве не относится? Ну части речи, наверное, можно разобрать, их и `Pymorphy` вроде умеет, `pos tags` это называется, но чтобы вот такое строить - ну, это очень специфическая тема. Посмотрим, ответит ли кто.

Comment: Да да, относится. Но мне хотелось бы узнать, какие слова относятся к нужному слову в подчиненной роли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение было найдено. Модуль Natasha при синтаксическом разборе даёт каждому слову head_id, которое представляет из себя id родителя. Например:

```
┌──────► Автобус     nsubj
│     ┌► ,           punct
│ ┌─┌─└─ едущий      
│ │ └──► сюда        advmod
│ └────► ,           punct
└─────┌─ остановился 
      └► .           punct
SyntaxMarkup(tokens=[SyntaxToken(id='1_1', text='Автобус', head_id='1_6', rel='nsubj'), SyntaxToken(id='1_2', text=',', head_id='1_3', rel='punct'), SyntaxToken(id='1_3', text='едущий', head_id='1_1', rel='acl'), SyntaxToken(id='1_4', text='сюда', head_id='1_3', rel='advmod'), SyntaxToken(id='1_5', text=',', head_id='1_3', rel='punct'), SyntaxToken(id='1_6', text='остановился', head_id='1_0', rel='root'), SyntaxToken(id='1_7', text='.', head_id='1_6', rel='punct')])
```

Comment: О, это хорошо. Я с `Natasha` просто давно разбирался и поверхностно. Наверняка там ещё фич добавили с тех пор.